# How to place text over an image at particular position using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

My project is an online exam using CodeIgniter. once a student completed an online exam, I need to display the marks on the mark sheet image. I need to display student name, student photo, register number, mark a particular position in an image.

I have tried to place text over an image using PHP using below function
imagettftext, image copy, imagecreatefromjpeg. in wamp server, it's working. when I copy the same program in xampp it shows a black background.
these function not working in CodeIgniter also.   How to do this using CodeIgniter?

I have tried this in core PHP. It's working.

```
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left5,$top5  , $white_color, $font_path, 'MSO');
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left6,$top5, $white_color, $font_path, '100');
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left7,$top5, $white_color, $font_path, '70');
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left8,$top5, $white_color, $font_path, '70%  A');


imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left6,$top6, $white_color, $font_path, '100');
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left7,$top6, $white_color, $font_path, '70');
imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left8,$top6, $white_color, $font_path, '70%  A');


imagettftext($our_image, $size,$angle,$left9,$top7, $white_color, $font_path, date('d/m/Y'));
$im2 = imagecreatefromjpeg("cmimage/studentphoto.jpg");
imagecopy($our_image,$im2,1900,1140,-80,-80,360,400);
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's not the code. Maybe you're not having GD library installed on the XAMPP system.

Comment: how to install gd libaray on xampp?

Comment: extension=gd2 is enabled in php.ini file